# Paid Adminstrative Leave

Tags: resignation

I just resigned from my job of 18 years, giving 3 weeks notice in order to tie up remaining projects - the next day I was put on paid administrative leave and locked out of emai, laptop and phone system.  Is this legal in California?

Comment: While this is a legal question, it is one that professionals should know, making it on topic for this site.

Comment: @jmoreno so you mean professionals should know **all** the legal intricacies... what would be the point of lawyers then?

Comment: @SolarMike: I didn’t say they should know all, I said it is within the bounds that is acceptable to this site.  The OP isn’t asking for legal advice, a lot of people (both in and out of California) know that it is an at-will state, and know the answer to this question. There is no reason to vote to close.

Comment: @jmoreno accusing me of voting to close is a **very** poor error of judgement on your part... I have not voted to close this question, but others clearly have.

Comment: @SolarMike: I did not accuse you of voting to close, I was reiterating the reason for my initial comment.

Comment: @jmoreno my first comment to you did not mention voting to close, so your action of putting it in your reply directed to me was clear.

Comment: @SolarMike: last comment.  My initial comment was directed at the vote to close users.  My answer to your first comment explained why I made my initial comment and what I meant by it.  My third comment (as well as my 4th aka this comment) is meant as a defense against the accusations that I am attacking you.  I am not attacking you, and have only referenced you so to bring my comments to your attention after you have referenced me. Toodles...

Comment: Legal or not, I personally wouldn't care. If I give my notice then it's pretty clear that I don't want to work there anymore. If you put me on paid administrative leave and then prevent me from doing any work then I'm going to have a nice three week paid vacation.

Comment: Seems like [hush money](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hush_money).

Answer (score 6):

> Is this legal in California?

Yes, it's perfectly legal.

Be happy that you are being paid.

Answer (score 2):

Legal or not (and I won't go there), it is becoming common business practice so you don't spend 3 weeks doing sabotage.

Many places will do that and class it as holiday, to be "wrapped up" with holiday and final pay etc.

Sadly some have been known to cause damage in their last week(s) of employment. Others will happily work for the company passing on their knowledge, you sound like you are very much in the second category and are sad that that time is now lost.

Comment: Putting people on "administrative leave" to prevent sabotage is kind of pointless. A motivated saboteur would plant things to cause trouble _before_ announcing their resignation, in anticipation of their access being cut off.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is legal.  While it **could** be consider fiscally irresponsible, given that there is a clear company benefit (protection of the company on one hand, and new employee acquisition on the other), it wouldn’t be fraud or anything else that would justify a criminal case against the company board or executives, or even a particular manager if it wasn’t company policy.

Even if your manager was family, and doing this **against** company policy to give you extra time off, it wouldn’t be illegal, although in that case it would certainly be grounds for terminating your manager.